# Checkpointing In ALS Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs, apache-spark-mllib

I just want to ask on the specifics how to successfully use checkpointInterval in Spark. And what do you mean by this comment in the code for ALS: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/recommendation/ALS.scala

If the checkpoint directory is not set in [[org.apache.spark.SparkContext]],
  * this setting is ignored.

1. How can we set checkPoint directory? Can we use any hdfs-compatible directory for this?
2. Is using setCheckpointInterval the correct way to implement checkpointing in ALS to avoid Stack Overflow errors?

**Edit**:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How can we set checkPoint directory? Can we use any hdfs-compatible directory for this?

You can use `SparkContext.setCheckpointDir`. As far as I remember in local mode both local and DFS paths work just fine, but on the cluster *the directory must be a HDFS path*.

> Is using setCheckpointInterval the correct way to implement checkpointing in ALS to avoid Stack Overflow errors?

It should help. See [SPARK-1006](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-1006)

**PS:** It seems that in order to actually perform check-point in ALS, the `checkpointDir` must be set or check-pointing won't be effective [Ref. [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/1c751fcf488189e5176546fe0d00f560ffcf1cec/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/recommendation/ALS.scala#L638).]

Comment: thanks for giving me tips on posting stack overflow. @zero323, just want to follow up if you have some ideas on the problem that I have.