# Spark Exception Error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-toree

I recently encountered this error in Spark (Apache Toree). I'm trying to factorize a matrix (roughly 4000 x 1000). It ran well with smaller iterations ( es 10, 15) but with larger iterations (I only tried 50 for now), I get this error message everytime.

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checkpointing In ALS Spark Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34634770/checkpointing-in-als-spark-scala)